# PDO submitting duplicate records?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

My registration code works, but it submits a duplicate every time.  For example, if I try to submit

`Steve Smith stevesmith@gmail.com 123456789`

It will show up in the database twice, like this

`Steve Smith stevesmith@gmail.com 123456789`

`Steve Smith stevesmith@gmail.com 123456789`

Here is my code

```
$failed         = "<p class='errormsg'>Registration failed!</p>";
$register       = "<p class='errormsg'>Thank you for registering $firstname $lastname</p>";
$adduser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO basicuserinfo(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname)");
$adduser->bindValue(':email', $email);
$adduser->bindValue(':password', $hash);
$adduser->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
$adduser->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
$adduser->execute();
    if(!$adduser->execute())
    {
    echo "$failed";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "$register";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are calling `execute` twice, remove the first `exeute`,

```
$failed         = "<p class='errormsg'>Registration failed!</p>";
$register       = "<p class='errormsg'>Thank you for registering $firstname $lastname</p>";
$adduser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO basicuserinfo(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname)");
$adduser->bindValue(':email', $email);
$adduser->bindValue(':password', $hash);
$adduser->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
$adduser->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
// $adduser->execute();    // <<== this should be removed,
                           //  the reason for duplicate records
    if(!$adduser->execute())
    {
       echo "$failed";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "$register";
    }
```

Comment: thanks! it worked! but what about the                        'if(!$adduser->execute())
    {
       echo "$failed";
    }'

Comment: is there anything wrong with it? obviously you can't remove that or else you will not be executing `:)`

Comment: the if statment is what was executing it twice?

Comment: No, you made two calls to the same method.  You called `$adduser->execute();` all alone on a line, and then you called it again in `if (!$adduser->execute())`.